# PHP push value array from one in another

Tags: php, arrays

i have two arrays and want to get one

```
//first

        [0] => Array (
        [drink] => A
        [litres] => 100.05
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [drink] => B
        [litres] => 3943
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [drink] => C
        [litres] => 1.46
        )


  //second      

        [0] => 22
        [1] => 12
        [2] => 16
```

The result should be:

```
[0] => Array (
    [drink] => A
    [litres] => 100.05
    [price] => 22
    )
[1] => Array (
    [drink] => B
    [litres] => 3943
    [price] => 12
    )
[2] => Array (
    [drink] => C
    [litres] => 1.46
    [price] => 16
    )
```

i tried with loops , merge etc all i should find on this site. But i dont get it.

```
foreach ($arr as $array2) {
    $array1[] = array( 'price' => $array2 );
}

print_r($array1);
```

i dont get it

Thanks in advance

Comment: A loop should work fine. Show us your current code.

Comment: `code foreach ($arr as $array2) {
 $array1[] = array( 'price' => $array2 );
}

print_r($array1);` yes i tried but i dont get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array_map(function($i, $j) { return array_merge($i, array('price'=>$j)); }, 
                    $arr1, $arr2);
```

**[demo on eval.in](https://eval.in/794840)**

Answer (score 0):

Short solution using `array_map` and `array_merge` functions:

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b){
    return array_merge($a, ['price'=>$b]);
}, $arr1, $arr2);

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [drink] => A
            [litres] => 100.05
            [price] => 22
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [drink] => B
            [litres] => 3943
            [price] => 12
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [drink] => C
            [litres] => 1.46
            [price] => 16
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct methods, I just want to show how it can be done with a `foreach()` loop:

Code:

```
$a=[
    ["drink"=>"A","litres"=>100.05],
    ["drink"=>"B","litres"=>3943],
    ["drink"=>"C","litres"=>1.46]
   ];
$b=[22,12,16];

foreach($a as $i=>$subarray){
    $a[$i]["price"]=$b[$i];
}
var_export($a);
```

This method is not a one-liner but will run slightly faster because it has fewer function calls and it will also be easier to read by most people.  (Though I'll admit -- I lean toward one-liners)  Note, my method doesn't declare a new result variable, it just extends the first array.

Output (as desired):

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'drink' => 'A',
    'litres' => 100.05,
    'price' => 22,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'drink' => 'B',
    'litres' => 3943,
    'price' => 12,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'drink' => 'C',
    'litres' => 1.46,
    'price' => 16,
  ),
)
```